# Exercise 28 of Chapter 3(Concrete Mathematics)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Solve the recurrence
>   $a_0 = 1$
>   $a_n = a_{n-1} +\lfloor\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\rfloor,n>0$

*I have managed to prove that:*

> *If* $a_n = m^2$ for some $m \in N^*$ then we must have
>   $a_{n+2k+1} =(m+k)^2+ (m-k)$ and $a_{n+2k+2} = (m+k)^2 +2m$,where $0\leqslant k \leqslant m$ **(*)**

using induction. However,the book also mentions:

> The solution can be rewritten in a nice form:
>   $a_{n-1} = 2^l + $$\lfloor({n-l\over{2}})^2\rfloor$ where $2^l+l\leqslant n < 2^{l+1}+l+1$.

I do spot out the pattern of $a_n$:the sequence of $a_n,a_{n+1},...,a_{n+2m}$ described by **(*)** is followed by $a_{n+2m+1}=(2m)^2$,which starts a new similar sequence(with different m and n)

I've tried to understand the equivalence with this idea in mind but still haven't made any progress. Could you provide me with some hints?

Comment: Your sequence is [OEIS sequence A002984](https://oeis.org/A002984).